# Comparing HAVEGE and Jitter Entropy algorithms

Tags: random, entropy, haveged

How does the [HAVEGE](https://www.issihosts.com/haveged/) method (or rather, the specific  adaption of it as used in `haveged`) for generating randomness from timing differ from that of the [Jitter Entropy](https://www.chronox.de/jent.html) method? Is there any research showing any major difference between their ability to extract quasi-non-deterministic randomness from CPUs? The former is a bit older and doesn't appear to get as much attention, whereas the latter is designed around modern CPUs and has even been [upstreamed into Linux](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/crypto/jitterentropy.c).